# Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format in difftime function

Tags: r, difftime

I am applying `difftime` function on the columns `started`*`_at` and `ended`*`_at` and the data type of both columns is "character" but i am getting the following error.

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

[image]

I tried this code

```
all_trips$ride_length <- difftime(all_trips$ended_at, all_trips$started_at, units = "secs")
```

Comment: Please add a reproducible sample of your data using something like `dput(all_trips[1:5,])`

Answer (score 0):

Use `strptime` to get POSIX format first.

```
difftime(strptime('4/1/2019 0:02', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'), strptime('4/1/2019 0:09', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'), units='secs')
# Time difference of -420 secs
```

I.e.

```
difftime(strptime(all_trips$ended_at, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'), strptime(all_trips$started_at, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'), units='secs')
```